# Where was Canadian political graphic satirist John Henry Walker's "Human Races" drawing published?

Tags: political-history, canada, race

John Henry Walker was a 19th century Canadian illustrator [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MG101.jpg) who produced political graphic satire in several publications including a short-lived one he founded, 'Punch in Canada' [2].

One particular image I am interested in are the ones archived in the McCord Museum Canada [3] depicting one iteration of the 'five-race' model of humanity, then increasingly used in strands of biology and anthropology and other sciences, in what is now termed as 'scientific racism' [4].

[image]

I would like to know where, if at all, in any of his published works, was this image used?

Thanks

PS: This question was also asked in the subreddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/history/comments/enxall/uses_of_image_of_race_in_the_published_works_of/

Notes:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MG101.jpg) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Henry_Walker

[2] https://canadianaci.ca/Encyclopedia/punch-in-canada/

[3] http://collections.musee-mccord.qc.ca/en/collection/artifacts/M991X.5.300; http://collections.musee-mccord.qc.ca/en/collection/artifacts/M930.50.1.17; http://collections.musee-mccord.qc.ca/en/collection/artifacts/M930.50.2.54; http://collections.musee-mccord.qc.ca/en/collection/artifacts/M930.50.8.286

[4] http://apa.nyu.edu/hauntedfiles/about/timeline/